# How to keep Reporting services table in the same page

Tags: rdlc

Is it possible to keep table column within the same page? It always go to the new page when table width is larger than page.

I design a report with **TableA** that have dynamic columns. The dynamic columns are in short format. For example: BS, BN, OT...

In order to understand column meaning, I have to create another table, **TableB**, below the table to explain. I want to display it horizontally. For example: BS: Basic Salary| BN: Bonus| OT: Over Time|  ...

But when **TableB** has many columns, It go to new page and leave a lot of blank space in previous page. I want to keep columns in the same page, if possible.

I want **TableB** to display like this:

|X:xx| X:xx | X:xx| X:xx| *(Edge of right page)*

|X:xx| X:xx|

Comment: Please add more details; at present it is hard understnding your actual problem.

Comment: I have add some more information. Please help me. Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a `horizontal table`, a great tutorial is described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f99179a2-d333-4572-a414-093c6b5e15ba/rows-into-column-conversion?forum=sqlreportingservices)

You probably have most of the horizontal table figured out, just this part is important to your issue.

> **Step 4**
>   Right-click on the column header and select "Edit Group".  Enter this
>   for the group expression: =RowNumber(Nothing). This will cause the
>   matrix to give you one column per row of data. Since horizontal tables
>   can end up rather wide, you probably want your table wrap around to
>   the next "line" after a specific number of columns.

Just simply count the number of rows that fit your page exactly and define this number in your column group expression as described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Use Column Visibility to hide column instead of Cell Visibility. This should eliminate the blank space.

If the report is still too big, set the report interactive size to 0in,0in. This will keep everything in one page.

Comment: It still does not work. Table still go to the new page and leave blank space.

Comment: Display horizontally, only one row but dynamic columns. Ex. BS:Basic Salary| BN:Bonus|OT:Over Time...